# arcanist arc help command with PHP CONFIGURATION ERRORS

Tags: php, vagrant, phabricator, arcanist

good day! 
I installed `arcanist` with:

```
git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git
git clone https://github.com/phacility/arcanist.git
```

but when I'm doing `arc help`, I get error like this:

```
$ arc help
PHP CONFIGURATION ERRORS
You need to install the cURL PHP extension, maybe with 'apt-get
install php5-curl' or 'yum install php53-curl' or something similar.
```

but I can run this: `curl " XXXX  "`, it's ok. and `curl_init()` also is run . with `phpinfo()`， I can see curl enable. But I don't know why get this error when I'm doing `arc` command.
Can you help me? Thanks!

and system information:

- my php version : 5.6.3
- vagrant box  on mac

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `curl` extension is enabled *for CLI SAPI* (likely in `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/` folder). CLI and web (mod-php or fpm) configurations are separate, so it very well may happen that extension is enabled when PHP is used through web server, but disabled when you run in as a CLI executable.

Comment: i run php -v ,show:
PHP 5.6.30 (cli)
so,it's enabled for cli sapi.

Comment: `php -v` doesn't show extensions, so it doesn't tell anything if *curl extension* is enabled. You can use `php -m` to show enabled extensions though.

Comment: em,thanks.i do it (php -m),i do not see curl. so what's next ? install curl extension.can u tell me the details?sorry,i am not good at php config or install. thanks you.

Comment: You can try `phpenmod -s cli curl` if that's available on your guest OS

Comment: no,i run "phpenmod -s cli curl" and get   -bash: phpenmod: command not found . so it is not contribution for my question. i need some else solution.